# ¿ Como dar estilos al texto de una funcion php?

Tags: php, css, funcion, estilos

Quiero añadir una clase al texto que impimira la función `imprime_aviso_correctamente()` para luego dar los estilos que desee, pero no se como hacerlo correctamente

¿ Donde debo añadir la clase exactamente?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'imprime_aviso_correctamente', 11 );

function imprime_aviso_correctamente() {

   wc_print_notice( __( 'este es el texto que se imprimira', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );

}
```

Comment: Cambia `'este es el texto que se imprimira'` por el texto con la clase que quieras. Por ejemplo: `'<p class="unaClaseCSS">este es el texto que se imprimira</p>'`, ahí el texto estará dentro de un elemento `p` y tendrá la clase `unaClaseCSS`, luego, en el `.css`, declaras los estilos para ese contenido.

Comment: Gracias, si das una respuesta la aceptare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia `'este es el texto que se imprimira'` por el texto con la clase que quieras.

Por ejemplo:

```
'<p class="unaClaseCSS">este es el texto que se imprimira</p>'
```

Haciendo eso, el texto estará dentro de un elemento `p` y tendrá la clase `unaClaseCSS`, luego, en el .css, declaras los estilos para ese contenido.

Veamos un ejemplo donde asignamos el color rojo al texto:

```css
.unaClaseCSS {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p class="unaClaseCSS">este es el texto que se imprimira</p>
```

Queda claro que puedes combinar clases o lo que sea, ya eso depende de lo que necesites o quieras hacer.

Por ejemplo si pones:

```
'<p>Tu balance no está en números <span class="green-text">verdes</span>, sino que está en números <span class="red-text">rojos</span>, considera no seguir gastando</p>'
```

Y defines el .css adecuado, tendrás parte del texto en verde o en rojo, según cada clase.

Veámoslo en un snippet:

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.green-text {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Tu balance no está en números <span class="green-text">verdes</span>, sino que está en números <span class="red-text">rojos</span>, considera no seguir gastando</p>
```

Y así, puedes combinar tu contenido como lo necesites, sin importar el nivel de complejidad.